# Search for records where one item in an array contains an attribute

Tags: mongodb, database

I have a collection containing documents. Each document has a `part` attribute containing an Array of Hash (documents). These documents may or may not have a `_encwas` attribute.

```
{ 
  _id : "00001",
  parts : [
    { _encwas: 1, body: "" },
    { body: "" }
  ]
},
{ 
  _id : "00002",
  parts : [
    { _encwas: 1, body: "" },
    { _encwas: 2, body: "" }
  ]
},
{ 
  _id : "00003",
  parts : [
    { body: "" },
    { body: "" }
  ]
}
```

Is there a quick way to find all records where at least one part contains a `_encwas` attribute?

The following query works

```
db.collection.find({ "parts.0._encwas" : { $exists : true } });
```

but I would love to find a way to replace `0` with `any part`. For example

```
db.collection.find({ "parts.*._encwas" : { $exists : true } });
```

The query should be as efficient as possible (I don't mind if I need to create additional indexes) because I need to iterate more than 1M records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seemed to work when I tried with your test data:

```
db.collection.find( { "parts._encwas": { $exists : true } } )
```

Moreover, you can find all documents containing _encwas having a specific value using:

```
db.collection.find( { "parts._encwas": 4 } )
```

...where 4 is the value...

I believe the relevant part of the documentation is here: [Dot Notation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29)

Comment: +1. Yes, that is how multi-valued (array) fields are supposed to work.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. It returns all the records containing parts, regardless they contain `_encwas`.

Comment: Ok, I found the issue. It should be `$exists : true`. I fixed your answer.